# How can I add an object property to the global object in rhino javascript

Tags: javascript, rhino

I have some properties in an object that I would like to add to the global namespace. In javascript on the browser I could just add it to the `window` object like so:

```
var myObject = {
  foo : function() {
    alert("hi");
  }
  // and many more properties
};

for (property in myObject) {
  window[property] = myObject[property];
}

// now I can just call foo()
foo();
```

But since rhino doesn't have the global window object I can't do that. Is there an equivalent object or some other way to accomplish this?

Comment: I figured out how to do it without having to write extra javascript: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60783337/473201

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `this`, which refers to the global object if the current function is not called as a method of an object.

Comment: var window = this; at the very beginning of the script helped me out. See the env.js script by John Resig http://ejohn.org/blog/bringing-the-browser-to-the-server/

Comment: @Miles, Hmm, don't you think that pnewhook's solution is better?

Answer (score 11):

I found a rather brilliant solution at [NCZOnline](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2008/04/20/get-the-javascript-global/):

```
function getGlobal(){
  return (function(){
    return this;
    }).call(null);
}
```

> The key to this function is that the this object always points to the global object anytime you are using `call()` or `apply()` and pass in null as the first argument. **Since a null scope is not valid, the interpreter inserts the global object.** The function uses an inner function to assure that the scope is always correct.

Call using:

```
var glob = getGlobal();
```

`glob` will then return `[object global]` in Rhino.

Comment: Brilliant! Remember that this will not work in ES5 strict mode, so your script may fail once Rhino [introduces ES5-conformance](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=517860).

Comment: cool thanks. `function getGlobal(){return (function(){return this})()}` is simpler and equivalent (confirmed by the author)

Comment: @user123444555621, Why wouldn't this work in ES5 strict mode?

Comment: It will return `null` instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode/Transitioning_to_strict_mode#this_in_function_calls

Comment: Jsfiddle showing that this [does not work in ES5 strict mode](https://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/tses04da/) even if  `getGlobal`  itself doesn't have "use strict" (but is within another function that is marked as "use strict"

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I've done it in the past:

```
// Rhino setup
Context jsContext = Context.enter();
Scriptable globalScope = jsContext.initStandardObjects();

// Define global variable
Object globalVarValue = "my value";
globalScope.put("globalVarName", globalScope, globalVarValue);
```

Comment: Why not simply use `this`?

Answer (score 1):

You could just define your own `window` object as a top-level variable:

```
var window = {};
```

You can then assign values to it as you please. ("`window`" probably isn't the best variable name in this situation, though.)

See also: [Can I create a 'window' object for javascript running in the Java6 Rhino Script Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964392/can-i-create-a-window-object-for-javascript-running-in-the-java6-rhino-script-e)

Answer (score -1):

I've not used rhino but couldn't you just use var?

i.e.

```
var foo = myObject.foo;
foo();
```

Edit:
Damn knew there'd be a catch! Miles' suggestion would be the go in that case.

Comment: Hah! Too simple for me :) Thanks!

Comment: Ah, wait...here's my real problem. I want to do this programmaticaly. I don't actually know the names of the object properties before hand.

Comment: This answer is unfortunately just clutter, as such could it be deleted? No hard feelings!