# Dynamically declaring functions in Rhino JS context

Tags: javascript, java, rhino

I'm currently attempting to declare functions dynamically in my Rhino JavaScript context. I have gotten to the point where I can declare variables/properties dynamically, but can't figure out how to pass a function as the value for a property. Here's how far I have gotten:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Member;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Context;
import org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject;
import org.mozilla.javascript.Scriptable;
import org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Context jsContext = Context.enter();
        try {
            Scriptable scope = jsContext.initStandardObjects();
            ScriptableObject fooObject = new ScriptableObject() {

                @Override
                public String getClassName() {
                    return "MyFoo";
                }
            };

            scope.put("foo", scope, fooObject);
            fooObject.putProperty(fooObject, "oneProperty", "This is the value of oneProperty");

            Member myFunction = /* What goes here? */ null;
            fooObject.putProperty(fooObject, "doStuff", new FunctionObject("doStuff", myFunction, fooObject));

            Object resultProp = jsContext.evaluateString(scope, "foo.oneProperty", "<cmd>", 1, null);
            Object resultFunc = jsContext.evaluateString(scope, "foo.doStuff()", "<cmd>", 2, null);

            System.out.println("Property value: " + Context.toString(resultProp));
            System.out.println("Function value: " + Context.toString(resultFunc));
        }
        finally {
            jsContext.exit();
        }
    }

}
```

I think I am correctly defining the "foo" object within the global scope and setting the property `oneProperty` on it, but I can't figure out how to give that set method a function. Am I doing this correctly? How can I do it for a function?

**UPDATE**
It looks like one can create a new class that implements the `Function` interface, implement the "call" method, and ignore the other methods that are required for that interface (just return null). That can then be given to the `putProperty` call. This seems to work, however it's painful to see in code and it is not clear from reading it what it does. I am still looking for a better solution, if one exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a java class with some functions you want to bind to js. Then use `class.getMethod` to get the Method object to create a `FunctionObject` and finally put it to js scope.

Here 's a demo in Kotlin language:

```
class Container{
    companion object{
        @JvmStatic
        fun foo() = true
    }
}

val ctx: Context = Context.enter()
val scope = ctx.initStandardObjects()

val fMethod = Container::class.java.getMethod("foo")
val f = FunctionObject("foo", fMethod, scope)
scope.put("foo", scope, f)

ctx.evaluateString(scope, "foo()", "<cmd>", 1, null) // the result should be true
```

However, non static function will be much more complex, yuo can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16479685/1089998).