# Where are parseInt() and parseFloat() located?

Tags: javascript

I see parseInt() and parseFloat() when I hit TAB in the console.

I can just type:

```
parseInt('123asd');
```

But where are these located?

Comment: Which console are you referring to ?

Comment: They're located in your computer three bits to the left of the microprocessor...They're in the global scope if that's what you're asking.

Comment: `function parseInt() { [native code] }`

Comment: @Barry: Chrome's console, but also Node.js.

Comment: @zzzzBov They are in the global **namespace**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are properties of the global object. (built-in functions)

In the case of the browser, this is `window`.

Comment: Or a different global object if you're not in a browser DOM (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162998/how-can-i-add-an-object-property-to-the-global-object-in-rhino-javascript).

Comment: @Dominic "... they are part of ..." could be misinterpreted or cause confusion. A better phrasing would be: "They are properties of the Global object". Also, note that in writing it is best to capitalize the word "Global", because parseInt and parseFloat are, technically, also global objects.

Comment: Also, `parseInt` and `parseFloat` are not technically part of the DOM, they are [built-in functions](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_4.3.25), part of the ECMAScript standard. The BOM/DOM are part of the [host environment](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_4.3.8)...

Comment: @Šime: Not convinced about your capitalization comment: the spec refers to it without capitals, except in headings (where everything is capitalized).

Comment: @Tim I tend to think of the Global object as God, so it comes naturally to me to capitalize it. :) But don't things that are unique get capitalized in the English language? For example, the Internet.

Comment: @Šime: It's a slightly complicated topic, and even as an enthusiastic native English speaker I'm not sure of the rules, since the principle of capitalizing a unique noun is not consistently applied. Even "the Internet" is not universal: "the internet" is becoming more common (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_capitalization_conventions#The_argument_for_common_noun_usage)

Comment: @Tim Then I guess it's a matter of preference. BTW I am capitalizing it for the same reason that I'm capitalizing constructor function names... to reduce confusion. (Because there is only one Global object, but many global objects.)

Answer (score 2):

parseInt and parseFloat are attached to the "Global" javascript object therefore they are available in all contexts.

Comment: But why can't I use global.parseInt('123asd'); then on Node.js

Comment: @ajsie `global.parseInt` works for me in Node..