# Using javax.script or Rhino to run javascript in Java with browser context (e.g. envjs)?

Tags: java, javascript, javax.script, protovis, envjs

I am trying to run [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/) javascript from a Java program using `javax.script`:

```
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
engine.eval(new java.io.FileReader("protovis-d3.1.js"));
```

In order to run this, the JavaScript engine needs to have all the context of a web browser.  The best option for this seems to be [envjs](http://groups.google.com/group/envjs).  Unfortunately it seems that the version of Rhino included in the JVM [isn't up to date](http://groups.google.com/group/envjs/browse_thread/thread/605ab50e70ad851d) and doesn't include everything that's necessary for envjs.

Has anyone had any success working with a browser context from javax.script, or am I missing something?

This is related to this question: ["Can I create a ‘window’ object for javascript running in the Java6 Rhino Script Engine"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964392/can-i-create-a-window-object-for-javascript-running-in-the-java6-rhino-script-e).

Answer (score -1):

You might want to look at http://jrex.mozdev.org/

It seems that you want to embed the full browser functionality within the JVM.

Also check
http://ejohn.org/blog/bringing-the-browser-to-the-server/